# Manually controlling an order in which tasks are executed

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task

I have a RabbitMQ queue that I read asyncrounusly in batches, but I must preserve order of these messages. I have a field named `ServiceNumber` which defines a unique number of the message, and this order I have to keep.

For example

```
   SN1 SN2 SN1 SN1 SN1 SN2
   1   2   3   4   5   6
```

In this case we can process messages 1 and 2 sumultaneously (they have different SNs), then we can process 3 and 6, then 4, then 5.

I tried to implement it via `ContinueWith` chain in a following manner:

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, Task> _currentTasks = new Dictionary<string, Task>();
private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

private async Task WrapMessageInQueue(string serviceNumber, Func<Task> taskFunc)
{
    Task taskToAwait;
    await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        _currentTasks.TryGetValue(serviceNumber, out var task);
        if (task == null)
            task = Task.CompletedTask;

        taskToAwait = _currentTasks[serviceNumber] = task.ContinueWith(_ => taskFunc());
    }
    finally
    {
        _semaphore.Release();
    }

    await taskToAwait.ConfigureAwait(false);
}

void Main()
{
    Task.Run(async () => {
        var task1 = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            return WrapMessageInQueue("10", async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(5000);
                Console.WriteLine("first task finished");
            });
        });

        while (task1.Status == TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("waiting task to be picked by a scheduler. Status = {0}", task1.Status);
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }

        var task2 = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            return WrapMessageInQueue("10", async () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("second task finished");
            });
        });
        
        await Task.WhenAll(new[] {task1, task2});
    }).Wait();
}
```

The main idea here is that the first RUNNED task should be finished before all the rest start. So I implemented a dictionary, where I store a task, and each subsequent one gets added into `ContinueWith` chain. Thus, it gets executed strictly after the previos one gets executed. When the 3rd task arrives, it gets its place in the queue, and so on.

But for some reason it doesn't work and the output is

> second task finished
>
> first task finished

What's wrong with this code? Is there any better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this code fragment

```
task.ContinueWith(_ => taskFunc());
```

doesn't do what you expect. It creates a task, which will just *start* the continuation, but not *wait* for it. As a result your both continuations are invoked immediately.

All in all you have too many unnecessary tasks there which are partially not properly awaited. I cleaned it up and implemented the continuation function you need to make it work.

```
public static
class TaskExtensions
{
    public static async
    Task ContinueWith(this Task task, Func<Task> continuation)
    {
        await task;
        await continuation();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static readonly Dictionary<string, Task> _currentTasks = new Dictionary<string, Task>();

    private static
    Task WrapMessageInQueue(string serviceNumber, Func<Task> taskFunc)
    {
        lock (_currentTasks)
        {
            if (!_currentTasks.TryGetValue(serviceNumber, out var task))
                task = Task.CompletedTask;

            return _currentTasks[serviceNumber] = task.ContinueWith(() => taskFunc());
        }
    }

    public static
    void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var task1 = WrapMessageInQueue("10", async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(500);
                Console.WriteLine("first task finished");
            });

            var task2 = WrapMessageInQueue("10", async () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("second task finished");
            });

            await Task.WhenAll(new[] { task1, task2 });
        }).Wait();
    }
}
```

Comment: Good job, however, a it doesn't work as expected too: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iE7vQ5

Comment: I'll test it with that now.

Comment: I fixed a link, you can see an output `first task finished
4 task finished
3 task finished
second task finished
`. It's unstable so it require several runs to be obvious.

Comment: It doesn't work because you wrap in WrapMessageInQueue's in Task.Run-s which you don't need. Try to call them the way I did.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that. I will try it in a real app and BRB if it uses your approach ro run tasks (and thus it works) or mine (thus I have to look for something extra)

Comment: The problem is that there you get the connection between the tasks lost almost the same way as in the former ContinueWith

Comment: Great job, it works as expected. I'd also like to emphasize that you have seen that there is no need in `async` so it could be replaced with a regular `lock`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `Task.Run` to add your test tasks into the queue and have a race condition here — there is no guarantee that `task1` will be picked by the thread pool earlier then `task2`.

Not sure if that's really the case anyway.

You may want to check [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) library, I assume that it's pretty suitable for described scenario.

Or even group by SN with use of Reactive extensions and then process.

Comment: I believe that TPL is an overkill here, I already have an async producer and I just have to return a Task that represent message processing. It already handles everything like buffering an so on for me. Rx looks interesting, however I'm not sure that it's suitable. As I said, I just have a callback that returns task. If I will place them in some kind of external queue then I'l lose confirmation at the first place. I could emulate it via TaskCompletionSource, but it's seems too complicated too. Anyway, I'd like to know why this code doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy Am I wrong about race condition in your testing code?

Comment: Well, it seems that I don't get executed in `fire-and-forget` manner as I expected before, so my code doesn't show a real use case. Sorry for that. You were right all this time so I upvote you too. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting approach. But since the processing of the messages (by SN) has to be sequential anyway, why do you one task per message? It just makes things more complicated, because you need to control the execution order of the tasks.

Why not have a collector task which sorts the incoming messages into queues (by SN) and starts one task per SN to process the queue?

Comment: Because it's how the queue consumer [works](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/blob/develop/Source/EasyNetQ/IAdvancedBus.cs#L55)